# start /b cmd /c does not work when task owner is not logged in

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task that starts a batch script `A.bat`. The task is set to run whether the user is logged in or not, using my credentials (I am an admistrator for the system).

`A.bat` is succesfully started according to the schedule. However, `A.bat` uses another batch script `B.bat`. `A.bat` contains the following command.

```
start /b cmd /c C:\folder\sub-folder\B.bat
```

On a computer running windows 10 the above line of the batch script fails if I am not logged onto the machine, but works if I am logged on. On other computers that use windows 7, the script runs without issue whether I am logged on or not.

If I instead use `call C:\folder\sub-folder\B.bat` the script runs without issue (whether I am logged on or not) on all the machines, both windows 10 and windows 7.

Since I did not write `A.bat`, I would like to know if there is any reason that I should be cautious replacing `start /b cmd /c` with `call`. Additionally, is there any reason for the difference in behaviour on windows 10?

Comment: No, whoever did that did not know what they wanted to do... why not just stick with `call B.bat`.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard "whoever did that did not know what they wanted to do", looking at the style of the rest of the code in this particular section of the batch script, I can believe that is the case. But since this is a work setting I was hoping for some justification beyond, this works and that doesn't (though that is probably sufficient since the script was not written internally so nobody will be offended).

Comment: write full path to `b.bat` as running without user logged, will start on system folder

Comment: also maybe https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=49165#p49165
or
https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=49201#p49201

Comment: start location is defined in the task, additionally the full path of `B.bat` is used, I merely simplified for the question. I have edited to make this clearer

Comment: then, run the task under a well known user account, with access rights to whatever `b.bat` does. the diference in behaviour, I think is related to the links I gave you

Comment: @AaronHayman, it is great to be minimal with your code but it also has to be [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Squashman what do you feel would be needed in addition to make this complete and verifiable?